# How to resize UIButton to fit UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a UIButton over a UIImageView.  I want the button to adjust its size to fit the imageview.  I tried a few different ways but can't get it.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add some padding like this:

```
NSInteger padding = 10;
CGRect newFrame = myImageView.bounds;
newFrame.origin.x += padding / 2.0;
newFrame.origin.y += padding / 2.0;
newFrame.size.width -= padding;
newFrame.size.height -= padding;
myButton.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: sorry, i set the content mode of the uiimageview to aspect fit.  so there's some blank area around the edge of the picture.  so i guess what i need to know is how to get the size of the imageview minus the blank area caused by the aspectFit.

Comment: I added some padding. How about that?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a custom button **with** an image-view in **Interface-Builder**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use--

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"];// image to be use
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];// set button frame accordingly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    [btn sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(img.size.width, img.size.height)];
```